# Branch has Nothing to compare in Github

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I want to add some new files to my friend's Repository. When I try to submit PR, it shows me nothing to compare. I have also checked the branch that is being compared is correct. If she adds me as a collaborator in Repository, then it doesn't count as my (Contributed to in GitHub Stats).

Also, I followed these steps:

1.Forked my friend repository.

2.Cloned into my PC.

3.Made new branch and added the new files

4.pushing code to MY GitHub which was forked by my friend.

5.Trying to SUBMIT a PR that shows nothing to compare as I have just added some files to the project. **PROBLEM OCCURRED AT THIS STEP**

#### What should I do now? in order to add code to her repository.

One possible solution is:

1.she adds me to the contributor's list.

2.I am able to push code to her repository directly

3.**BUT THIS DOESN'T ADDS TO MY OPEN SOURCE CONTRIBUTIONS OR MY GITHUB STATS IN (Contributed -To)**

Thus help me, please and correct me if I am doing anything wrong!
It's feeling like I am contributing open source but I am not being shown as contributing to someone.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ok, guys! Finally, I solved this myself.

What wrong I was actually doing was:

- Made a new folder(other than the cloned folder) and added new files there only without adding the old files.
- Made a remote to my GitHub repo where I pushed code into a new branch.
  -Trying to submit PR and thus, there is shown me that I was not able to submit a PR as we had totally different files.

Solution:

- Cloned the local repo and then do changed it in the cloned folder only.
- Then push the code into your Github Repo.
- Submit a PR and it will add a contribution to it.

#### PS: I was a beginner to Open Source Contribution. Thus, I learnt a new thing.

Answer (score 0):

> pushing code to MY GitHub which was forked by my friend.

The problem is: you need to push to your GitHub repository that *you* have forked from your friend's repo.
Not your repo forked by your friend.

If you push directly to your friend's repository, it will [count as contribution](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile#what-counts-as-a-contribution) if you are pushing to the default (usually '`main`') branch.

Comment: Hi @VonC I forked my friends repo only. And I pushed code to my repo only. But when I try to submit a PR, it is showing nothing to compare as we both have different commits history.

Comment: How to directly push to my friends repo in her master branch? Note: if she adds me as an collaborator, then it doest counts as my contribution in 'Contributed to' in GitHub Readme Stats. Please contact me on LinkedIn for futhur doubts. https://www.linkedin.com/in/akshit-mangotra

Comment: @AkshitMangotra Strange: pushing on the main branch of your friend repository should count as contribution, according to the GitHub documentation.

Comment: hi@ Stange: Yes, i am trying to push to main branch only by submitting a PR from my repo to her repo. But its showing me nothing to compare.